# Messaging service within my app

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to implement a message service into my app that works exactly like this:

1. users register with a nickname within the app
2. they can add contacts (just nicknames) and send them a message by just specifying their nickname
3. they can send a message whenever they want, and the message is stored on a server until when the receiver connects to internet.
4. when a message is received, a push notification is triggered.

So, the messages work pretty much like emails, however instead of using email addresses, we only use usernames. I'm also going to build my own back-end for it.

Which APIs should I use or which 3rd party framework can I use ?
And any tip ?

**N.B.** I need to make it work with iOS 3.0 as well.

and in the future I will develop an Android app, so the nicknames should be unique and I should be able to send messages from iPhone to Android devices within the same app.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be Push Notifications

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used the [Three20](http://three20.info/) library and would recommend giving it a try. It's an open source spin-off originated by the author of the Facebook app. It features a bunch of additional GUI components that might be useful to your project, like a message composer that resembles the one used by Apple's email app.

Also, Three20 features a nice framework for handling navigation within your app. Currently, the biggest drawback seems to be that certain features don't play well with the iPad API.

Comment: @cg I see, but I actually need APIs for the messaging services. This is my problem number one.